# Strange side effect of a PHP post query code in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, blogs, posts

Why this code in functions.php has this strange side effect of switching the menu to the mobile version in not-home pages in wordpress?

```
function my_blog_category( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_home() && !is_front_page() || is_archive()) {
 $query->set( 'cat', '6');
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_blog_category' );
```

This code should affect only posts in blog and archive page so why's that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you were asking:

- If `$query->is_home() && !is_front_page()`
- Or, `is_archive()`

Group your conditional expression using brackets.

```
function my_blog_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && ( !is_front_page() || is_archive() ) ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '6');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_blog_category' );
```

Now you're asking:

- If `$query->is_home()`

  - And, if `!is_front_page()` or `is_archive()`

Comment: The code was working before, the problem was not the code itself but its side effect of completely changing the nav with the mobile version that obviously at desktop width has "display:none;" so in the end I have the right posts query but no primary menu. This is odd.